# Why am I not being able to connect to my database?

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, qt

I've followed numerous tutorials to the tee, yet I still cannot connect to my database from Qt.  I always get this error:

```
Closed!  "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBMSLPCN]SQL Server does not exist or
access denied. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBMSLPCN]ConnectionOpen 
(Connect()). [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute   
QODBC3: Unable to connect"
```

or if I use SQL NATIVE CLIENT (i.e. instead of SQL SERVER) as the DRIVER, I get the following error:

```
Closed!  "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default 
driver specified QODBC3: Unable to connect"
```

Been sitting here for hours trying to figure this out, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.  The server, database, etc all seem to have the right names.  I just don't see why it's not connecting.

Code below

```
#include "login.h"
#include "ui_login.h"

login::login(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::login)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase ("QODBC","Chessgames");
    db.setConnectOptions();
    db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=MYNAME\\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=Chessgames;Uid=sa;Password=xxxxx;");

    if(db.open())
    {
       qDebug() << "Opened!";
       db.close();
    }

    else
    {
       qDebug() << "Closed! " << db.lastError().text();
    }
}

login::~login()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Have you added the MYNAME to the hosts file ? SQL Server have the TCP/IP enabled ? The SA password is correct ?

Comment: Add MYNAME to the hosts file?  I have not done that.  I have tcp/ip enabled and the sa password is correct, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to open by changing the hostname to the ip address and port.

```
db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=192.168.X.X;Port=port#;
                   DATABASE=Chessgames;Uid=sa;Password=xxxxx;");
```

Comment: This solution didn't work for me ...

EDIT :
I just saw on an other post something that seems to work for me so I share it here : 
I replaced `DRIVER={SQL Server};` by `DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};`